# get uploaded file details in next step of a multistep form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to module development .
I am creating a multi step form .
on the first step i am uploading a image file .
In the next step i have some form fields and want to display the image and other details of the image .
I have successfully uploaded the image file but unable to get the file details in the form .
I have read the druapl file api but didnot find any solution .

Thanks and Regards
Parth

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
$fid = $form_state['values']['file_element_name'];
$file = file_load($fid);
```